# PostScript new page in a loop

Tags: postscript

I've got a problem with the newpage operator. I have the following code

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0

/txtArray [(a) (b) (c) (d)] def

/fontSize 12 def
/lineHeight fontSize def
/lineHeight lineHeight 1.5 mul def

/Arial findfont fontSize scalefont setfont

/x 50 def
/y 400 def

txtArray
{
    /y y lineHeight sub def
    x y moveto
    show
} forall

showpage
100 200 moveto
(Hello) show

%%EOF
```

I want a newpage after printing the array but I can see only the array elements. The string 'Hello' is not displayed. In the next step I want to write the newpage operator in the loop to get a newpage after every array element.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator called `newpage` in standard PostScript, do you mean `showpage` ?

Your program does exactly what you asked it for. After drawing the contents of the array you execute `showpage`, that transfers the accumulated operations to the output buffer and ejects the page. Having done that, you then proceed to make some more drawing operations, but you don't call `showpage` again. The program then terminates. Since you didn't call showpage after those drawing operations, the accumulated operations are not transferred to the output.

Whenever you want to transfer the accumulated drawing to the output you need to call `showpage`. (NB this also erases the page after transferring the data)

So if you put a `showpage` **after** `(Hello) show` then you will get a second page with Hello on it.

Comment: Yes of course, I mean showpage. Your solution works. But I'm wondering why the evince Document Viewer only shows one page. If I convert the ps to pdf with ghostscript the PDF contains all pages. If I use the following code`%!PS-Adobe-3.0

%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
/pgsave save def
%%NeededResource: font TimesRoman
%%EndPageSetup
 
showpage
%%Page: 2 2
%%BeginPageSetup
/pgsave save def
%%NeededResource: font TimesRoman
%%EndPageSetup
 
showpage

%%EOF` I can see all pages in evince

Comment: Well, when I try your program here using Ghostscript 9.50 and the pdfwrite device, 'gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf test.ps' the output file only has a single page.... The example in the comment above has two executions of showpage, so yes, it will produce 2 pages. I presume Evince is using Ghostscript to handle PostScript input.